# sshd is not starting on rhel 7.7

Tags: rhel, sshd

Job for sshd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

```
> -- Unit sshd.service has begun starting up. ctl sshd[4845]: error: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use. ctl
> sshd[4845]: error: Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in
> use. ctl sshd[4845]: fatal: Cannot bind any address. ctl systemd[1]:
> sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a ctl
> audispd[584]: node=servername type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER
> msg=audit(xxx.xx:yyyy): pid=4845 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
> subj=system_u:syste Mar 08 12:07:00 ctl systemd[1]: Failed to start
> OpenSSH server daemon.
> -- Subject: Unit sshd.service has failed
> -- Defined-By: systemd
> -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
> -- Unit sshd.service has failed.
> -- The result is failed. Mar 08 12:07:00 ctl audispd[584]: node=servername type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER msg=audit(1583669220.759:5500):
> pid=4845 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:syste Mar
> 08 12:07:00 ctl systemd[1]: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
> Mar 08 12:07:00 ctl audispd[584]: node=servername type=CRYPTO_KEY_USER
> msg=audit(1583669220.759:5501): pid=4845 uid=0 auid=4294967295
> ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:syste Mar 08 12:07:00 ctl systemd[1]:
> sshd.service failed. Mar 08 12:07:00 ctl audispd[584]: node=servername
> type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1583669220.760:5502): pid=1 uid=0
> auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:i [root@server
> conf]# :system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=sshd comm="systemd"
> exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=?
> res=failed' M
```

I have tried checking the services listening on port 22

```
netstat -tunlp | grep 22

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1023/sshd

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1023/sshd
```

I saw that tcp6 and tcp are listening on port 22 and tried disabling ipv6

referenced [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-linux/) and disabled ipv6

made changes to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Also edited grub
`/etc/default/grub` and added `ipv6.disable=1`

Even after reboot, I cant get the tcp6 to be disabled on port 22. What else can I check to resolve the sshd startup issues

List of processes running

```
ps -ef | grep sshd
root     1023     1  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/share/centrifydc/sbin/sshd -D
root      1899  1023  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
root      1900  1023  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user  1994  1900  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user
ec2-user  1996  1899  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
root      3282  3268  0 13:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

Once I killed Centrify process, I was able to start sshd process.

Thanks
Nate

Comment: Your netstat shows a `sshd` already running (pid 1023) and listening, which is what I would expect. Can you run `ps -ef | grep sshd` for us?

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, ps -ef | grep sshd
root      1023     1  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/share/centrifydc/sbin/sshd -D
root      1899  1023  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
root      1900  1023  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user  1994  1900  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user
ec2-user  1996  1899  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
root      3282  3268  0 13:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sshd

Comment: CentrifySSH has taken over your ssh service. Was that your intention?

Comment: Thanks Jeff and Ulrich. It worked.

Comment: If you need them both, have CentrifySSH use another port so that it can run alongside openssh-server.

Comment: Thanks Nasir, I will check with admins

Answer (score 0):

List of processes running

```
ps -ef | grep sshd
root     1023     1  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/share/centrifydc/sbin/sshd -D
root      1899  1023  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
root      1900  1023  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user  1994  1900  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user
ec2-user  1996  1899  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
root      3282  3268  0 13:22 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

Once I killed Centrify process, I was able to start sshd process.                 Thank you to Ulrich and Jeff for help in resolving.